# What is proper way to advise failed transform w/ Spring Integration Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, transform, spring-integration, dsl

I have completed a "happy-path" (as below).

How I can advise a `.transform` call to have it invoke an error flow (via errorChannel) w/o interrupting the `mainFlow`?

Currently the `mainFlow` terminates on first failure occurrence in second `.transform` (when payload cannot be deserialized to type).  My desired behavior is that I'd like to log and continue processing.

I've read about `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.  Would I just add a second param to each `.transform` call like `e -> e.advice(myAdviceBean)` and declare such a bean with `success` and `error` channels?  Assuming I'd need to break up my `mainFlow` to receive success from each transform.

On some commented direction I updated the original code sample.  But I'm still having trouble taking this "all the way home".

```
2015-09-08 11:49:19,664 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler DEBUG handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.BeanNameMessageProcessor@5f3839ad] (org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler#0)' produced no reply for request Message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "hasDoaCostPriceChanged" (class com.xxx.changehistory.jdbc.data.RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog), not marked as ignorable (18 known properties: "supplierUpdateDate", "fPLOSMaskArrival", "createDate", "endAllowed", "sellStateId", "ratePlanLevel", "ratePlanId", "startAllowed", "stayDate", "doaCostPriceChanged", "hotelId", "logActionTypeId" [truncated]])
 at [Source: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@242017b8; line: 1, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.xxx.changehistory.jdbc.data.RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog["hasDoaCostPriceChanged"]), headers={id=c054d976-5750-827f-8894-51aba9655c77, timestamp=1441738159660}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,664 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel DEBUG postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "hasDoaCostPriceChanged" (class com.xxx.changehistory.jdbc.data.RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog), not marked as ignorable (18 known properties: "supplierUpdateDate", "fPLOSMaskArrival", "createDate", "endAllowed", "sellStateId", "ratePlanLevel", "ratePlanId", "startAllowed", "stayDate", "doaCostPriceChanged", "hotelId", "logActionTypeId" [truncated]])
 at [Source: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@242017b8; line: 1, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.xxx.changehistory.jdbc.data.RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog["hasDoaCostPriceChanged"]), headers={id=c054d976-5750-827f-8894-51aba9655c77, timestamp=1441738159660}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,664 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel DEBUG preSend on channel 'mainFlow.channel#3', message: GenericMessage [payload=java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@242017b8, headers={id=b80106f9-7f4c-1b92-6aca-6e73d3bf8792, timestamp=1441738159664}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,664 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler DEBUG org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream@242017b8, headers={id=b80106f9-7f4c-1b92-6aca-6e73d3bf8792, timestamp=1441738159664}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,665 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel DEBUG preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?, headers={id=24e3a1c7-af6b-032c-6a29-b55031fba0d7, timestamp=1441738159665}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,665 [pool-3-thread-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler DEBUG ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.BeanNameMessageProcessor@5f3839ad] (org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler#0) received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?, headers={id=24e3a1c7-af6b-032c-6a29-b55031fba0d7, timestamp=1441738159665}]
2015-09-08 11:49:19,665 [pool-3-thread-1] com.xxx.DataMigrationModule$ErrorService ERROR org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:369)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    ... 22 more
```

**UPDATED (09-08-2015)**

*code sample*

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime))
            )
            .transform(unzipTransformer())
            .split(f -> new FileSplitter())
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(persistentType()), , e -> e.advice(handlingAdvice()))
            // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to
            .aggregate(a -> 
                            a.releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() == persistenceBatchSize)
                            .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                            .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                            .groupTimeoutExpression("size() ge 2 ? 10000 : -1")
                            , null
            )
            .handle(jdbcRepositoryHandler())
            // TODO add advised PollableChannel to deal with possible persistence issue and retry with partial batch
            .get();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
public ErrorService errorService() {
    return new ErrorService();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel customErrorChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow customErrorFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(customErrorChannel())
            .handle("errorService", "handleError")
            .get();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice handlingAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnFailureExpression("payload");
    advice.setFailureChannel(customErrorChannel());
    advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

protected class ErrorService implements ErrorHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        stopEndpoints(t);
    }

    private void stopEndpoints(Throwable t) {
        log.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(t));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had things wrong in a few places, like:

- I had to autowire a Jackson2 `ObjectMapper` (that I get from Sprint Boot auto-config) and construct an instance of `JsonObjectMapper` to be added as second arg in `Transformers.fromJson`; made for more lenient unmarshalling to persistent type (stops `UnrecognizedPropertyException`); and thus waived need for `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`
- Choosing the proper variant of `.split` method in `IntegrationFlowDefinition` in order to employ the `FileSplitter`, otherwise you don't get this splitter rather a `DefaultMessageSplitter` which pre-maturely terminates flow after first record read from `InputStream`
- Moved `transform`, `aggregate`, `handle` to a its own pubsub channel employing an async task executor

Still not 100% of what I need, but it's much further along.

See what I ended up w/ below...

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class DataMigrationModule {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}")
private String accessKey;

@Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}")
private String secretKey;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucket}")
private String bucket;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.max-objects-per-batch:1024}")
private int maxObjectsPerBatch;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.accept-subfolders:false}")
private String acceptSubFolders;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.remote-directory}")
private String remoteDirectory;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.local-directory-ref:java.io.tmpdir}")
private String localDirectoryRef;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.local-subdirectory:target/s3-dump}")
private String localSubdirectory;

@Value("${cloud.aws.s3.filename-wildcard:}")
private String fileNameWildcard;

@Value("${app.persistent-type:}")
private String persistentType;

@Value("${app.repository-type:}")
private String repositoryType;

@Value("${app.persistence-batch-size:2500}")
private int persistenceBatchSize;

@Value("${app.persistence-batch-release-timeout-in-milliseconds:5000}")
private int persistenceBatchReleaseTimeoutMillis;

@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private final AtomicBoolean invoked = new AtomicBoolean();

private Class<?> repositoryType() {
    try {
        return Class.forName(repositoryType);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        log.error("Unknown repository implementation!", cnfe);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}

private Class<?> persistentType() {
    try {
        return Class.forName(persistentType);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        log.error("Unsupported type!", cnfe);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
    return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
}

@Bean
public FileToInputStreamTransformer unzipTransformer() {
    FileToInputStreamTransformer transformer = new FileToInputStreamTransformer();
    transformer.setDeleteFiles(true);
    return transformer;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource<?> amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
    AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource messageSource = new AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource();
    messageSource.setCredentials(credentials);
    messageSource.setBucket(bucket);
    messageSource.setMaxObjectsPerBatch(maxObjectsPerBatch);
    messageSource.setAcceptSubFolders(Boolean.valueOf(acceptSubFolders));
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    if (!fileNameWildcard.isEmpty()) {
        messageSource.setFileNameWildcard(fileNameWildcard);
    }
    String directory = System.getProperty(localDirectoryRef);
    if (!localSubdirectory.startsWith("/")) {
        localSubdirectory = "/" + localSubdirectory;
    }
    if (!localSubdirectory.endsWith("/")) {
        localSubdirectory = localSubdirectory + "/";
    }
    directory = directory + localSubdirectory;
    FileUtils.mkdir(directory);
    messageSource.setDirectory(new LiteralExpression(directory));
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime))
            )
            .transform(unzipTransformer())
            .split(new FileSplitter(), null)
            .publishSubscribeChannel(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(), p -> p.subscribe(persistenceSubFlow()))
            .get();
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow persistenceSubFlow() {
    JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy = new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(persistenceBatchSize,
            persistenceBatchReleaseTimeoutMillis);
    // @formatter:off
    return f -> f
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(persistentType(), jsonObjectMapper))
            // @see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to
            .aggregate(
                    a -> a
                        .releaseStrategy(releaseStrategy)
                        .correlationStrategy(m -> m.getHeaders().get("id"))
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        , null
            )
            .handle(jdbcRepositoryHandler());
    // @formatter:on
}

@Bean
public JdbcRepositoryHandler jdbcRepositoryHandler() {
    return new JdbcRepositoryHandler(repositoryType(), beanFactory);
}

protected class JdbcRepositoryHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Insertable repository;

    public JdbcRepositoryHandler(Class<?> repositoryClass, ListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        repository = (Insertable<?>) beanFactory.getBean(repositoryClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
        repository.insert((List<?>) message.getPayload());
    }

}

protected class FileToInputStreamTransformer extends AbstractFilePayloadTransformer<InputStream> {

    @Override
    protected InputStream transformFile(File payload) throws Exception {
        return new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(payload));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. To `advice` the `handle()` method of Transformer's `MessageHandler` you should use exactly that `e.advice` method of the second parameter of `.transform()` EIP-method. And yes: you should define `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` bean for your purpose.

You can reuse that `Advice` bean for different goals to handle successes and failures the same manner.

**UPDATE**

Although it isn't clear to me how you'd like to continue the flow with the wrong message, but you you can use `onFailureExpression` and `returnFailureExpressionResult=true` of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to return something after the `unzipErrorChannel()`.

BTW the `failureChannel` logic doesn't work without `onFailureExpression`:

```
if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
    Object evalResult = this.evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
    if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
        return evalResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Artem. I'm still struggling.  I've updated the flow and provide the trace once more; hopefully you have time for one more look?  Not understanding what else I need to do w.r.t. just logging and moving along (after a failed transform -- ideally I'd collect and write string (from `InputStream`) the `payload` to a renamed file e.g., `<filename>.failed.json`).  I do see that the error is logged but fails downstream in `ErrorService` with `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?`